# AS3 getting audio levels, tones, and other data?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, audio-recording

What audio data can I get using actionscript? Is it possible to get tones or levels, and what other data is available about the audio file?

So if I get audio from an mp3 or from recording, I want to get information about that audio instantly, perhaps the spikes and peaks so I can compare that audio with another piece of audio to see if it matches. It might be similar to voice recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With as3 and sound as ByteArray, pretty much anything can be done. The problem you'll likely be gated by is having to do a lot of low level stuff yourself, or having to rely on someone's libraries.

You can try the [tonfall](http://code.google.com/p/tonfall/) - a lot of power, not a lot of documentation though.

As long as you're not doing complex stuff but just level detection, the soundanalyzer class in the hype framework [examples](http://www.hypeframework.org/02_examples/soundanalyzer/content/05_soundanalyzer/) is a good place to start

Comment: the hype as3 framework has been replaced by a javascript framework, but the library can still be found on github. https://github.com/hype/HYPE_AS3/blob/master/src/hype/framework/sound/SoundAnalyzer.as